# What motivated revolutionary France to declare war on Britain in 1793?

Tags: france, 18th-century, international-relations, french-revolution

[France declared war on Britain in 1793](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolutionary_Wars#1793) (War of First Coalition). What was its motivation for declaring war? It was already at war with many European powers at the moment, and it was not likely in a position to defeat or conquer Britain. I understand if Britain had motivation to be at war with France (e.g. to stop republicanism or the French conquests in Europe), but I don't know what was to be gained by France from this. Wouldn't it be better to let Britain be neutral and deal with them later if needed?

Comment: "You can't declare war on us, because we declare war on you first. So take that!" Note that the British had already recalled their ambassador  in preparation for declaring war (possibly concerned that he might be denied safe passage if he didn't leave France first).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens is there such a logic? :) Isn't it better to not be the declarer, because at least you can claim you're not the aggressor?

Comment: @user69715: I think you're mistakenly trying to apply 21st century western values to the late 19th century.  Earlier times were perhaps more honest, in that countries often admitted that they went to war just 'cause they wanted to conquer the other country.

Comment: @user69715 Not all decisions/actions are rational or optimal. In this case the French perceived a coalition against them (as PieterGeerkens noted, partially justified in that England was mustering for war, though the ambassador was recalled much earlier upon the deposition of Louis XVI). The National Convention perceived London's dithering as a play for time, and believed it was better to attack before its enemies were ready. As it turns out they played straight into England's hands by taking on the role of the aggressor.

Comment: Note that the concept of `casus beli` has been long been integral to international relations in Europe. In this case, Britain certainly responded to the French declaration with the indignation of a victim of unprovoked aggression. The OP is not "mistakenly applying 21st century values" by any means.

Comment: Revolutionary Zeal?  Revolutionary France was a political ponzi scheme that could only survive by feeding the populist frenzy with more and more evidence that Revolutionary France was threatened on all sides.  If opponents didn't exist, they must be manufactured.  An early version of [securitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securitization_(international_relations) in which external opponents are substituted for bread and circuses and used to justify ever more extreme actions.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That's quite a broad brush; imho it describes the Reign of Terror rather better than early 1793, and through these years such energies were equally directed at internal "enemies".

Comment: While I recognize it applies to the reign of terror, I think it applies throughout the Revolution.  I grant you it is a broad brush (a comment).  But France's pre-emptive attacks were motivated by proto-securitization and French economic policy was based on conquest and looting. For all that people like to believe that the Revolution was full of noble souls, the truth is that they were pirates that would have starved to death if they didn't pillage their neighbors for money, food, soldiers, and fear.

Comment: @user69715: 18th century logic was the opposite of "ours." For instance, Frederick the Great said, "Better to prevent than to be prevented."

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP's own link, "Britain began military preparations in late 1792 and declared that war was inevitable unless France gave up its conquests, notwithstanding French assurances they would not attack Holland or annex the Low Countries."

France felt that she needed the outposts that she had captured in (modern) Belgium to further her Revolution. Britain was opposed to any such French expansion, and France knew that war was inevitable. Over a century later, in 1914, Britain and *Germany* went to war for essentially the same reason.

Being the "revolutionary" country, France wanted to make the first "declaration" and strike the first blow.